# SQL - Cleaning database from wrong First Name / Last Name

Tags: sql, equals, contains, startswith

I've got table where we store First Name ,Last Name and Company Name etc.

```
`customers` (
    `Company Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    `First Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    `Last Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
)
```

It contatins bad data , like :

```
Company Name | First Name | Last Name
--------------------------------------
Why Asking   | bbbToday   | cxzNot
Temp         | CCCttt     | xcy 
Blank        | John       | Travolta
Windows      | Johny      | Bravo
```

In second table I've got filter which I should use to clean the table :

```
`filter` (
    `operator` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
    `value` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL 
) 

operator   | value
------------------------
equal      | cxz
starts with| xcy
contains   | CCC
```

I want to select all data without bad data like :

```
Company Name | First Name | Last Name
--------------------------------------
Blank        | John       | Travolta
Windows      | Johny      | Bravo
```

I just try

```
select * from customers where not exists (select value from filter)
```

---

And it's ok , but it only works when value exist/not exist ,but the problem is  how I can check if for Example First Name starts with "xcy" or "CCC"  ?

Comment: What rdbms are you working with? (syntax suggests MySql).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should do what you need. You need to manually adapt the condition according to the content of the filter table :

```
SELECT c.*
FROM customers c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM filter f
    WHERE 
        ( f.operator = 'equal' AND (f.value = c.FirstName OR f.value = c.LastName))
        OR ( f.operator = 'starts with' AND (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT(f.value, '%') OR c.LastName LIKE CONCAT(f.value, '%')))
        OR ( f.operator = 'contains' AND (c.FirstName LIKE CONCAT('%', f.value, '%') OR c.LastName LIKE CONCAT('%', f.value, '%')))
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Matching text strings can be done with [the `LIKE` operator and a pattern](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE), or [the `SIMILAR TO` operator and a regular expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP).

Your example matches are simple enough that you can stick to the `LIKE` patterns. So now you need to construct a pattern for use with each one; [the `CASE` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE) can help.

Then, select those `customer` records where any field matches the generated pattern from a `filter` record. Those are the records you want to delete; or, you can exclude those records in some other query.

```sql
SELECT
    c.company_name,
    c.first_name,
    c.last_name
FROM customer AS c
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN operator = 'equal' THEN value
                WHEN operator = 'starts with' THEN concat(value, '%')
                WHEN operator = 'contains' THEN concat('%', value, '%')
            END AS match_pattern
        FROM filter
        ) AS f
        ON (
            c.company_name LIKE f.match_pattern
            OR c.first_name LIKE f.match_pattern
            OR c.last_name LIKE f.match_pattern
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
SELECT *
FROM customers c
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM filter f
        WHERE
            c."First name" LIKE f.startsWith + '%'
            OR c."First name" LIKE '%' + f.contains + '%'
    )
```

You did not say what DBMS you are using, so the exact syntax may vary a bit. For example in Oracle you will need to use the [CONCAT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm) function to add the percent sings.